What makes the children's book "Wild about Books" especially easy to read aloud?
I read a lot of children's books aloud to my child, many of which rhyme.  Among all such books, there is one in particular that is strikingly easy to read aloud - the words just roll right off my tongue and I rarely need to take a conscious breath.  The book is called "Wild about Books" by Judy Sierra.  I am wondering if there is some sort of explanation for this:

Why is it easier to read aloud?  Is it something about the rhythm? Sequence of sounds?
Is there some sort of language to describe the structure of the book (e.g. iambic pentameter)?
Is it easy to find other books with this or related structure?

I never studied literature deeply so the mechanism by which this works is quite mysterious to me.  The start of the book is below.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

It started the summer of 2002
When the Springfield librarian, Molly McGrew,
By mistake drove her bookmobile into the zoo.
Molly opened the door, and she let down the stair
Turned on the computer, and sat in her chair.
At first all the animals watched from a distance,
But Molly could conquer the strongest resistance.


Excellent question, by the way. Welcome to the site - good to have you.

The verse is in anapestic tetrameter, meaning that each line has four anapests, where an anapest consists of two unstressed syllables followed by one stressed syllable. If I indicate the stressed syllables in bold, and divide the lines into anapests with vertical bars, then the first three lines scan like this:

It start- | ed the sum- | mer of two | thousand two
When the Spring- | field librar- | ian Moll- | y McGrew
By mistake | drove her book- | mobile in- | to the zoo.

Not every line scans perfectly—for example, the opening line is missing a syllable at the beginning (this is known as a “headless” or “acephalous” line)—but they scan well enough that a reader can recognize the pattern and stress the right words so as to maintain the rhythm. For example, in the third line you have to stress “-take” and leave “drove” unstressed, whereas in some other context you might do the reverse.
Anapestic verse takes some skill to sustain, as the English language tends to stress rather more than one in three syllables, so poets tend to reserve it for special effects, for example, Robert Browning uses anapests to suggest the rhythm of galloping horses in ‘How They Brought the Good News from Ghent to Aix’:

I sprang to the stirrup, and Joris, and he;
I galloped, Dirck galloped, we galloped all three;
“Good speed!” cried the watch, as the gate-bolts undrew;
“Speed!” echoed the wall to us galloping through;
Behind shut the postern, the lights sank to rest,
And into the midnight we galloped abreast.

Swinburne uses anapestic trimeter to express the urgency of passion in ‘Dolores (Notre-Dame des Sept Douleurs)’:

There are sins it may be to discover,
    There are deeds it may be to delight.
What new work wilt thou find for thy lover,
    What new passions for daytime or night?
What spells that they know not a word of
    Whose lives are as leaves overblown?
What tortures undreamt of, unheard of,
    Unwritten, unknown?

Dr Seuss (Theodor Seuss Geisel) frequently uses the jauntiness of the rhythm for comic effect, for example, in his Sleep Book:

The news has come in from the District of Dofft
That two Offt are asleep and they're sleeping aloft.
And how are they able to sleep off the ground…?
I’ll tell you. I weighed one last week and I found
That an Offt is SO light he weighs minus one pound!


To put this in musical terms, the stress rhythm manifests as a triplet feel with 4 beats (in this case) per measure/line - it's an extremely regular, common and uncomplicated rhythm which should feel rather natural and familiar even without rhythmic training.

@NuclearHoagie I feel like this is also a meter that percussionists have a name for, like "paradiddle". This actually refers to the sequence of hands they use, but it manifests as stresses.

@Barmar I'd just call it a triplet feel or expect it to be in a triplet meter like 12/8. In terms of drum rudiments, it's like a Swiss army triplet without the flam (RRL or LLR repeated).
